# Difference between getContext() and requireContext() when using fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-context

I've been having this doubt since a long time, when I'm working with android fragments and I need to instantiate a Context, or I need to pass a Context as argument for other function, I can choose to use between getContext() and requireContext() methods to achieve that, I normally prefer to use requireContext(), but just because the IDE(Android Studio) shows warnings sometimes when I use the getContext().But the result of using one or other method seems to be the same, no matter what I choose.

My question is, is there any difference between these two methods? If this is the case, which one is better, or which should I use in each case?

Comment: use requireContext only when you are sure fragment is attached to its host(onResume, onViewCreated, etc)

Answer (score 94, accepted):

`getContext()` returns a nullable `Context`.

`requireContext()` returns a nonnull `Context`, or throws an exception when one isn't available.

If your code is in a lifecycle phase where you know your fragment is attached to a context, just use `requireContext()` to get a `Context` and also keep static analyzers happy about potential NPE issues.

If your code is outside of regular fragment lifecycle (say, an async callback), you might be better off using `getContext()`, checking its return value yourself and only proceeding using it if it was non-null.

Being explicit with nullability is even more important in Kotlin where it is built into the language's type system.

Comment: Then, the idea is to use requireContext() if I'm sure the fragment is attached (a view for example), but if not, getContext() and validate the result before continue. Very helpful information by the way

Comment: Can you provide some more examples for when a fragment might not be attached to a context? Or perhaps some examples for when we most commonly can be certain that it will be attached?

Comment: @AlanNelson It's attached between `onAttach()` and `onDetach()` and the regular fragment lifecycle occurs inbetween. https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/lifecycle - usual reason for getting null context for a detached fragment is trying to get the context too early e.g. in init phase, or out of lifecycle such as in an async callback.

Comment: "where you know your fragment is attached to a context" wasn't this always the problem with Android, that you got many NPEs because at places you though there shold be a context there wasn't any? I press a button, click listener in ListAdapter calls listener impl in Activity, in the meantime the activity goes to the background and when I want to use the context in the listener callback I don't have anymore for example?

Answer (score 12):

While Laalto's answer is correct, I'm adding the code to prove the difference between requireContext() and getContext.

In Fragment.java you should see the following code.

```
@NonNull
    public final Context requireContext() {
        Context context = getContext();
        if (context == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Fragment " + this + " not attached to a context.");
        }
        return context;
    }
```

You can see that the requireContext() method throws an exception when the context is null.

```
@Nullable
    public Context getContext() {
        return mHost == null ? null : mHost.getContext();
    }
```

On the other hand, If you see the code for getContext(), there is a chance that you might get a null value when called.

Comment: ok then, for what i'm seeing the getContext() has to be treated carefully in order to avoid exeptions and app crashes

Comment: @Ariel, you got it.

Comment: Actually, both methods may cause an exception if context is null. requireContext() immediately throws IllegalStateException, whilest getContext() may cause a NullPointerException down the road when you try to use its result. E.g getContext().getResources()

Comment: @Ridcully, agreed!