# Shared Preferences in Fragment with Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, sharedpreferences

I'm making a counter app in Android using Kotlin. My code is working great in MainActivity but when it comes to fragment it's not working anymore.

```kotlin
class HomeFragment : Fragment()
{
    private lateinit var homeViewModel: HomeViewModel

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View?
    {
        /*homeViewModel =
                ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)*/
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
        val textView: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_home)
        val button: Button = root.findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
        var nombre = PrefConfing.loadTotalFromPref(this)
        button.setOnClickListener {
            nombre++
            textView.text = "vous l'avez fait $nombre fois"
            PrefConfing.saveTotalTimes(applicationContext, nombre)
        }

        return root
    }
}
```

This is my Kotlin HomeFragment code, and there is my Java code:

```java
public class PrefConfing {
    private static final String TIMES = "com.example.alllerrr";
    private static final String PREF_TOTAL_KEY = "pref_total_key";

    public static void saveTotalTimes(Context context, int total) {
        SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences(TIMES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putInt(PREF_TOTAL_KEY, total);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public static int loadTotalFromPref(Context context){
        SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences(TIMES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return pref.getInt(PREF_TOTAL_KEY, 0);
    }
}
```

for the var `nombre` I can't add this to the context and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll know why:

If you chase inheritance of **Activity** class you'll find out that it inherits Context class so passing **"this"** has no problem,
But when you chase **Fragment** class inheritance (androidx.fragment.app.Fragment), you'll never find that class inherits **Context**, so it's not acceptable to pass **"this"** as Context.

Actually **getContext** and **requireContext** returns their host's context, so you need to use them instead.

> requireContext: returns a nonnull Context, or throws an exception when one isn't available.

> getContext: returns a nullable Context.

[see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60402600/9391162) more about difference between "getContext" and "requireContext".

Answer (score 1):

If in line

```kotlin
var nombre = PrefConfing.loadTotalFromPref(this)
```

You are getting:

```
Type mismatch.
Required: Context!
Found: HomeFragment
```

You have to do it like this:

```kotlin
var nombre = PrefConfing.loadTotalFromPref(requireContext())
```