# Should I use requireContext().getString(R.string.exampleString) or getString(R.string.exampleString) inside Fragment?

Tags: android

Should I use requireContext().getString(R.string.exampleString) or only getString(R.string.exampleString) inside Fragment?

Is there a difference, and is any approach better?

Comment: The best way is to directly use fragment method getString(id) without need to get context.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between getContext() and requireContext() when using fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60402490/difference-between-getcontext-and-requirecontext-when-using-fragments)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Require context:

```
/**
     * Return the {@link Context} this fragment is currently associated with.
     *
     * @throws IllegalStateException if not currently associated with a context.
     * @see #getContext()
     */
    @NonNull
    public final Context requireContext() {
        Context context = getContext();
        if (context == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Fragment " + this + " not attached to a context.");
        }
        return context;
    }
```

get string:

```
/**
 * Return a localized string from the application's package's
 * default string table.
 *
 * @param resId Resource id for the string
 */
@NonNull
public final String getString(@StringRes int resId) {
    return getResources().getString(resId);
}
```

then inside getResources:

```
/**
 * Return <code>requireActivity().getResources()</code>.
 */
@NonNull
final public Resources getResources() {
    return requireContext().getResources();
}
```

so, internally they both end up calling requireContext. might as well just use getString then, no difference really, using requireContext is just an additional call for no real value